# angular4 unit test raise ngModel update using select change event

Tags: angular, unit-testing

can't seem to be able to test the `ngModel` binding using `change` event for `select` control:

component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-area',
    templateUrl: 'app/test.component.html'
})
export class TestComponent {
  selectedFred;
  freds = [{name:"kruger"},{name:"Durst"}];
}
```

template:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedFred">
    <option *ngFor="let f of freds" [ngValue]="f">{{f.name}}</option>
</select>
```

test:

```
   it('should allow us to set a bound select field', fakeAsync(() => {
     let input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('select')).nativeElement;
      console.error(input);
        input.value = component.freds[1];
        input.selectedValue = component.freds[1];
        input.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
        tick();

        expect(component.selectedFred.name).toEqual('Durst');
    }));
```

plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZXJ6bsjfu78d4m928U8S?p=preview
what am i doing wrong?

similar unit test with `input` control works like a charm, see: https://plnkr.co/edit/0ELwf5W26XoBlKa5Y5xA?p=preview